# og tag doesn't working

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, share

I have empty og tag at first

```
<meta property="og:title" />
```

and after some function , I fill that og tag with specific text.

```
($("#popup_result").append(mode(answers_result)), $("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr("content", "I have: " + $(".trivia_final_result").text()))
}
```

Problem is that , after sharing it on facebook, new og tag content does not appear, but when I open inspect element it shows changed tag, in source code it is still empty.

Comment: Facebook will not read open graph data that is populated by javascript.

Comment: what is solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

As already said, Facebook will not read a tag populated by javascript as it does it's own scrape of the page when shared.

To do what you want to do, you need to share a link to the page where the og:meta is populated on the server. This can still be dynamic, maybe populated using a variable in the url, but it will have to be populated before the page is loaded.

You can see the meta Facebook sees by visiting the URL in the [Facebook linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

**EDIT:**

It may also be possible to achive what you want to achieve with the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5)